# idea reports "Cannot resolve variable 'result'" for spring @Cacheable(unless = "#result == null")

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, intellij-idea

my code is like

```kotlin
@Cacheable(unless = "#result == null")
fun get(key: String): String? {
  return dao.getById(key)
}
```

why idea think #result is a custom variable here?

Comment: I just copy pasted your code, and it works for me, I do not get any error/warning. Maybe something wrong with some dependencies, or an Idea cache thingy?

Comment: my idea verion is 2021.1.2 ult, and the warning is reported by Ispections -> Spring -> Spring Core -> Spring EL, what about yours?

Comment: tried 'invalid cache and restart' but the warning remains

Comment: Should be fixed by https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-153985

Comment: I have the same problem, do you solve it? thanks